Constrained extrema of $f(x,y)=\sin x \sin y$ where $0<x<\pi$ and $0<y<\pi$
I need to find extremes of function $f(x,y)= \sin(x) \sin(y)$ with conditions $0<x<\pi$ and $0<y<\pi$.
So, this is a constrained extrema problem. It could be solved using Lagrange multipliers.
$$F(x,y; \lambda) = f(x,y) - \lambda g(x,y).$$
I don't know what is function $g(x,y)$ in this example.
If the condition was, for example, $xy=1$, then $g(x,y)$ would be $g(x,y)=xy-1$.
But I don't know how to make $g(x,y)$ from the conditions $0<x<\pi$ and $0<y<\pi$.
Could you please help me? I need $g(x,y)$ to finish $F(x,y; \lambda)$ so I can find partial derivates.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

You need to divide your problem in two parts. One is the unconstrained problem. Then the second part is the constraint - minimize $f(x,y)$ when $(x,y)$ is on a boundary of the domain. You have 4 segments for the boundary: $x=0$, $x=\pi$, $y=0$, $y=\pi$. Solve the problem for each of them

@Andrei do you know how should function g(x,y) look like? I need function F(x,y;λ) to find partial derivates...

on one boundary $g(x,y)=x$, on one $g(x,y)=x-\pi$, then $g(x,y)=y$ and $g(x,y)=y-\pi$

The maximum of $\sin(x)$ over $0<x<\pi$ occurs at $x=\pi/2$ with $\sin(x)=1,$ its maximum value. The same happens for $\sin(y)$ over $0<y<\pi.$ Hence, the maximum value of the product will occur at $(x,y)=(\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and have value $1.$
The minimums are a different story: because the inequalities are strict, both $\sin(x)$ and $\sin(y)$ are forbidden from reaching $0$ which would otherwise be their minimum values. $f$ does not have a minimum value on the specified region.

thanks for answering
